# Calling a function every 1.5 seconds after a button is pressed

Tags: java, android

The function I have created now gives me a random number between 0.8 and 1.2 every time I click on a button within my android application and displays the result in a TextView. However, I would like for this function to keep giving me a new number every 1.5 seconds without having to click on the button continuously for a new result. How would I go about doing this?

Below displays the function I would like to call every 1.5 seconds.

```
public void generate(View view) {
    double min = 0.8;
    double max = 1.2;
    Random rand = new Random();
    double number = rand.nextDouble()* max;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_RanNum);
    String myString = String.valueOf(number);
    myText.setText(myString);
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Handler / Runnable:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;
Button buttonStart, buttonStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new Handler();
    buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonStop = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    });
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    });

}

public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        generate();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500); // 1500 miliseconds
    }};

public void generate() {
    double min = 0.8;
    double max = 1.2;
    double number;
    Random rand = new Random();
    TextView myText = findViewById(R.id.textView_RanNum);

    number = rand.nextDouble() * max;
    String myString = String.valueOf(number);
    myText.setText(myString);
  }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I will do more research on Handler/Runnable. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's Handler class to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler myHand = new Handler();
                myHand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      generate();
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
    }

    public void generate() {
        double min = 0.8;
        double max = 1.2;
        Random rand = new Random();
        double number = rand.nextDouble() * max;
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_RanNum);
        String myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);
    }
}
```

Read More about Handler here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: I will be sure to read more about handlers, thank you very much.